# Refreshing NERDTree upon directory change in Vimscript

Tags: vim, cd, nerdtree

Finally took the dive into vim a couple days ago and I've been having fun playing with my vimrc ever since.

I understand the premise of connecting the command `:NERDTree` to something else but I'm not sure what the best way to go about doing this would be. Is it possible to watch for when the active directory changes?

Comment: Entering :NERDTree updates NerdTree with the current active directory, I'd like it to be updated automatically whenever the directory changes.

Comment: You can't, it's not something that can be implemented in Vim. But `r` is a NERDTree mapping for "refresh cursor dir" (and `R` for "refresh root dir"), which is much more convenient than `:NERDTree`.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that it isn't possible. Can you not just bind the command that refreshes NERDTree to execute whenever :cd is entered? The goal is to accomplish it in one command.

Comment: Why not just navigate using NERDTree instead of using vim builtins and expecting it to keep in sync? That's kind of what it's for.

Comment: I guess that makes sense... not sure why that didn't occur to me.

Comment: *“Can you not just bind the command that refreshes NERDTree to execute whenever `:cd` is entered?”* No, sadly you can’t, because NERDTree makes that function, [`s:refreshRoot()`](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/15445be5fb2559829ac7a1f05af5d713586e8ec9/autoload/nerdtree/ui_glue.vim#L525), script-local. It’s a private function that can only be called by files within the NERDTree plugin. Though it seems you don’t need to worry about that to solve your particular use-case.